# Xamarin TabbedPage Performance When Using Children.Add

Tags: xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Good Afternoon,
 I have a question regarding the performance of the tabbed page and whether there is a more efficient way to load the tabs into the page, without any frame loss or process hang.
 Regarding this issue, I have been having a few issues with TabbedPage in Xamarin.Forms. My project currently consists of a Listview with 104 components. When I click on one of the items it opens up a tabbed page consisting of 3 tabed pages. I start the tabbed page using the following code

```
 int Clicked = 0;
 public async Task CheckClick(Page data)
 {
             Clicked += 1;
             if (Clicked == 1)
             {
                 await Navigation.PushAsync(data);
                 List_View.SelectedItem = null;
             }
 }
 public async void OnSelection(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
 {
             if (e.SelectedItem == null)
             {
                 return;
             }
             var Cell = e.SelectedItem as DataSource;
             switch (Cell.ID)
             {
                 case 0:
                     await CheckClick(new Function_One());
                     break;
        }
 }
```

The real problem comes after, whether I pre load the information ahead of time or do what ever, whenever I call Children.Add(data); the whole application hangs for 1 or 2 seconds and than allows the page to load. The code is as follows.

```
public class Function_One : TabbedPage
 {
    private async Task Test()
    {
                //
                var data = new NewPageData("", "", "OP.png", "Persian.png", Description, Usage, Storage, Data);
                var data2 = new NewMedicalPage(Medical_Info, Translation, startinfo);
                var data3 = new NewNotePage("", 0);
                data.Icon = "Info.png";
                await Task.Delay(100);// Little await to load the page first before hang
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =
                {
                    Children.Add(data);// HERE is the freeze
                    Children.Add(data2);// these
                    Children.Add(data3);// 3 (Adding of the Tabs)
                });
    }
    public void UpdateData()
    {
                Task.Run(async () =
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Description.Spans.Add(new Span
                        {
                            Text = "Data.... ",
                            FontSize = 18,
                            FontFamily = variables.fontFamily
                        });
                        Usage.Spans.Add(new Span
                        {
                            Text = "MoreData...",
                            FontSize = 18,
                            FontFamily = variables.fontFamily
                        });
                        Storage.Spans.Add(new Span
                     {
                         Text = "LastData...",
                         FontSize = 18,
                         FontFamily = variables.fontFamily
                     });
                     await Test();
                 }
                 catch { }
             }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    public Function_One()
    {
            UpdateData();
                BarBackgroundColor = MainColor;
                BarTextColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
                Title = "Page";
    }
 }
```

NOTE: (This Project Is Completely An Offline Project, No Internet Needed)

If anyone could explain to me a better method for loading the data while keeping the application flowing and smooth, that would be appreciated. The data does not have to load all at once, just as long as the page opens as soon as its clicked!

Comment: How you get idea to add pages to tab in `BeginInvokeOnMainThread`

Comment: It seems that you use    await Task.Delay(100);// Little await to load the page first before hang . Try to remove it.

Comment: @Arvindraja I add the children in the main thread, because they have to be added on the main UI thread, anything outside of that thread does not seem to have any affect.

Comment: @LucasZ I add the Task.Dekay(100); in order to make a smooth transition to the page, then the whole program hangs for a few seconds, then loads the data. I do this so it does not lag when first clicking the page. However I am looking for a way to circumvent the UI Hang completely, possibly platform specific, or anything honestly where I can load the pages in the background.

Comment: Seems to be a common issue not just tabbed pages.